# MySQL: Database design for procedure flow

Tags: mysql, database-design, procedure, knowledge-management

It's something like knowledge-based system. For example:

When a user go to first page, let's call it "How Can I Help You With?"
There will be 4 options:

1. In case of fire
2. Injured
3. There is a fight
4. Obedience

If the user selected **1 "In case of fire"**, it will ask them some other questions:

1. Can you use the fire extinguisher?
2. Is anybody hurt?

If the user selected **2 "There is a fight"**, it will ask them something like:

1. Is anybody hurt?
2. Security around?

Basically, if the user selected either **1 "In case of fire"** or **2 "There is a fight"**, there will be at least one question in common in the procedures.

The end point is a help article. For instance, if the user selected "Is anybody hurt?", that will be the end-point, where the user sees the help document.

How do I design the database for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation of the Bill Of Materials database.

One way to design this would be the following table:

```
Question
--------
Question ID
Previous Question ID
Question Text
Help Article URL
```

The Question ID is an auto-incrementing integer, and is the primary or clustering key for the table.  The Previous Question ID is null for your top level questions, and a pointer back to the Question ID for lower level questions.  The Help Article URL is null or points to a help article.

The question numbers are supplied by the application as it reads rows from the Question table.

Comment: Remember that in one question, users will be asked some other questions, not just another question

Comment: @Inguyen55: Yes.  The Previous Question ID is not a unique column.  Using your example in the question, "Can you use the fire extinguisher?" and "Is anybody hurt?" both point back to "In case of fire".